# highlight stand out(cout, cerr) or qDebug

Tags: c++, qt

there are many messages need to display when a program running. some of them are indicate to some errors occurred. it's difficult to find them.

i find `qWarning`, `qCirical`, `qFatal` in Qt, but there also can't highlight the messages it output.

i use the keyword `highlight cerr` or `highlight qDebug` to search, there is a [essay](http://brianmilco.blogspot.com/2011/11/color-debug-output-with-qt-and-qdebug.html) redefine the `MsgHandler` to implement this.

is there some native（esay or needn't write code） method to implement this?

Comment: If on windows this will do it: http://pastebin.com/a6AZBTdr I don't know linux well enough to say so I won't post this as an answer I guess..

Comment: Are you looking for a cross-platform solution? In case not, which operating system are you using?

Comment: @LaszloPapp i use Qt in windows. but i'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: @stamaimer: I do not think there is a cross-platform solution, so a valid answer would be it is not possible, and you would have to code it yourself.